# Possible to install Reporting Services 2000 against SQL Server 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2000

Does anybody know if it is possible to install SSRS 2000 and have the report database resident in SQL Server 2005? How would you go about it? The install refuses to get past the setting of the report server database:

```
"The Report Server Database is a different version and cannot be used for this installation"
```

I wonder if perhaps there is some hidden setting of if I could install against 2000 and them update the database.

Answer (score 0):

I read the error message here incorrectly. It is not so much that the SQL Server is too new but rather than the report server database(which already existed from a previous install) is too new. Likely it was patched bu one of the service packs which made it unrecognizable to the installer. Deleting the report database fixed the issue although the report data was lost.